# How to use OMBD API in a web project?

Tags: html, json

First of, happy thanksgiving everyone!

Now, onto the question at hand. For my web programming project my partners and I decided to use the OMBD API, it is a "do whatever you want" type of project so we decided to create something similar to the rotten tomatoes website since our first project was similar in nature, except that this one is going to be vastly more expanded also using the Microsoft cognitive services.

Looking at the ombdiapi website the usage is rather simple, you pass the specific query you are interested in to the url and it returns a json or xml file depending on the return type specified. What I was wondering is how does one both set the url, execute it, then fetch the data via a web project?

We never used any external apis, only frameworks really but those were easy to set up using a simple cdn. Any examples would be appreciated.

Ex of query: http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=the+matrix&r=json

returns:

```
{"Title":"The Matrix","Year":"1999","Rated":"R","Released":"31 Mar 1999","Runtime":"136 min","Genre":"Action, Sci-Fi","Director":"Lana Wachowski, Lilly Wachowski","Writer":"Lilly Wachowski, Lana Wachowski","Actors":"Keanu Reeves, Laurence Fishburne, Carrie-Anne Moss, Hugo Weaving","Plot":"A computer hacker learns from mysterious rebels about the true nature of his reality and his role in the war against its controllers.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"Won 4 Oscars. Another 33 wins & 43 nominations.","Poster":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDMyMmQ5YzgtYWMxOC00OTU0LWIwZjEtZWUwYTY5MjVkZjhhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDYyMDk5MTU@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"73","imdbRating":"8.7","imdbVotes":"1,244,275","imdbID":"tt0133093","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: This seems fairly broad, can you clarify what exactly you want to know? If you want to see examples how this is done, I'd start by searching something like `jquery get data from json api` (if using jQuery is an option)

Comment: Yeah, using jquery is allowed. Doing a quick search for "html parse json" I see that jquery has a .getJSON which takes a url. Would that be how I would fetch the data then? with the url being a var I could manually append the required parameters?

Comment: Yup, that sounds like the way it's typically done.